# Jquery email validation of email and one specific message

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a jquery syntax as below

```
Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
        url: "emails.php",
        type: "post",
          },
```

which validate a field as below;

```
<td class="field" style="width: 246px">
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" style="width: 246px">
</td>
<td class="status"></td>
```

which displays a success/error message in `<td class="status">`

It validate the data when a valid email ID is entered.

The ajax callback is a simple true/false data.

What i want is, it should also validate when a specific message "NA" is entered in the field. Is this possible??

Here is the complete javascript;

```
<script id="demo" type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
        rules: {
            ID: "required",
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
            },
            Address: "required",
            Dept: "required",
            Phone: "required",
            College: "required",
            LDate: "required",
            EDate: "required",
            Year: "required",
            Privilage: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
        url: "emails.php",
        type: "post",
          },
            },
            LibID: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            ID: "Enter ID",
            Name: "Enter Name",
            Address: "Enter Address",
            Phone: "Enter Phone Number",
            College: "Specify College",
            LDate: "Enter Licenseing Date",
            EDate: "Specify License Expiry Date",
            Year: "Specify Year",
            Dept: "Specify Department",
            Privilage: "Specify Privilage",
            username: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
                remote: jQuery.format("username not available")
            },
            Email: {
                required: "Enter a valid email address",
                minlength: "Enter a valid email address",
                remote: jQuery.format("already registered"),
            },
            LibID: {
                required: "Enter a Library ID",
                minlength: "Enter a Library ID",
                remote: jQuery.format("ID is already in use"),
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.html("OK").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
    $('.username').alphanumeric({nocaps:true}).alphanumeric({ichars:'._'});
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance :)

blasteralfred.

Comment: emails.php returns a simple true/false. it is already modified so as to return true for value NA (case sensitive)

Comment: I am using jquery.validation plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the jquery.validation plugin.
If thats the case you can use depends with email rule:

```
Email: {
 required: true,
 email: {
   depends: function(element){
     return element.value != "NA";
  }
 },
 remote: {
    url: "emails.php",
    type: "post",
 },
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery.validation plugin. This works !! Thanks.. :)